# In SSRS is there a way to change the default properties

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

It's pretty annoying having to go through all my text boxes and change can grow to False. Is there a setting in report builder to change the default property from True to False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy to do.

1. Select all the text boxes you want to change the property on; use Ctrl and click to select more than one.
2. Find the CanGrow property in the Properties Pane, change it to False.

This should work in both Report Builder, and VS.

Comment: Wow how dumb of me. I really thought I tried multiple selection but obviously I didn't...